# Windows 7 Safe Mode with networking and full Graphics

Tags: windows-7, graphics, safe-mode

I would like to be able to run Windows 7 with networking as well as full graphics.

I already have Safe Mode with Networking, Sound but would also like full normal Graphics

cheers

Comment: You can't. `Safe Mode` does not load the drivers required to do this. Windows 7 requires hardware to do full graphics, and safe mode, by design does not load the required drivers to do this.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound for helping me to resolve my query 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of Safe Mode is to load the MINIMUM required to load Windows, so you can fix it. There is no reason that Microsoft would implement this, and could bust your computer even more! There is the `VGASAFE` driver that gets loaded so you can at least try to fix your computer.

If you want networking, sound and full graphics, you need to run it in Normal mode. If there is a reason you can't, I'd suggest opening a new question and explaining the issues you're running into, as well as what you've tried already.

Comment: Thank you Canadian Luke. Are you able to provide an solution to my question? cheers

Comment: @MarkRowe Use "autoruns" or "Msconfig" instead to reduce or stop things in normal mode.